# Problems connecting to web socket server in Azure Container Instances

Tags: c#, .net, azure, docker, .net-core

We have developed a websocket server (with a Tcplistener) in .net core 3.0. I can run it locally on my computer in a docker instance with port mapping. 
With a websocket test client I can confirm that a connection can be opened. I'm trying to deploy it to Azure Container instances. I can confirm that the 
websocket server starts up and is running but when I try to connect to it with a testclient it fails(i.e no handshake is done/tcp traffic is there). 
I read blog post that you can't do port mapping for Azure Container instances.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: you might not be able to (re)map a port but for sure can expose any port you like. did you do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @silent. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: do you expose the port that your program listens on when you create the container instance?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but windows based containers often startup and run whatever they are meant to before the instance has any network access. Not true of Linux containers btw. So I had to put retry logic in for when it happens and can often be 30s before the program has network access.

Comment: @silent: yes I do.

Comment: @simon: can you share some code for this? I am actually running it as Linux containers.

Comment: @jopa it's just basic retry logic on the first piece that accesses something on the network, i.e. blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), 3); but this issue of network connectivity is only related to Windows container instances